# SF85P Employment history

Tags: security-clearance

I have put everything honestly in my SF86P form. I dont have any criminal or financial history. Nor got fired.

But, I was wondering if for one of my employments (3.5 years ago), I can write some other managers name who was not my supervisor as my supervisor?

Since my actual supervisor and I had some issues and he raised concerns on performance and had to leave eventually on mutual terms. The other manager was in good terms with me and is willing to vouch for me and sits in the same address where i used to go to work. Where as my actual supervisor works in a different state.
If I write my actual supervisors name he would probably mention that he is not eligible for rehire for 1 more year or something and also that i had to leave coz of performance issues, and I have to check that option in the form as well.

Answer (score 4):

> But I was wondering if for one of my employments (3.5 years ago), I can write some other managers name who was not my supervisor as my supervisor?

**That is not a good idea**.

When the new company finds out after doing the background check, they will conclude that you are not telling the truth. Consequently, things will be very complicated for you.

I would recommend that you write the correct info on the SF86P form. Then, you can explain things to the new company later on if necessary.

Comment: For a security check, they are much less interested in your work history than in whether you are honest about your work history, unless you were dismissed for gross incompetence, gross negligence, criminal activity or violating company security policies. If you feel you have to lie about it, don't apply for jobs which require security clearance.

Comment: @keshlam, Exactly. Also, when you lie about your supervisor name, they will surely find out about that from HR. That is a guarantee.

Comment: damn. okay. so if i select the option which says left after getting a notice on performance, does that automatically disqualifies me for public trust check? Or I can still get clearance? 
Also the person sent me the form said he can give a pre-clearance in 1 week and then can reach out to the CURRENT employer since I dont want them to know I am trying to leave company. What is the process after pre clearance and what happens after?

Comment: @maddy, If you go through the technical interviews and pass all the technical tests/questions, it means at least they think your technical skills are acceptable for their jobs. In addition, they can train you on-the-job furthermore. If this is true, then maybe they don't really care if you had performance issues in the past with former companies because your tech skills may have improved now.